# How do I generate a list of strings per id?

Tags: postgresql

I want to list what brands each customer buys. I have the same "customer_id" feilds showing up repeatedly with a name of different brands (shown as column title: "name") they purchased in this code. I'd like to group by the customer_id and show a list of brands  for each customer_id. I get the error message:

> "ERROR:  function group_concat(character varying, unknown) does not
>   exist 
>                                                                ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need
>   to add explicit type casts.

```
    CREATE TEMP TABLE customer_brandids AS 
SELECT receipts.receipt_id, receipts.customer_id, receipt_item_details1.brand_id
FROM receipts
LEFT JOIN receipt_item_details1
ON receipts.receipt_id = receipt_item_details1.receipt_id;

SELECT customer_brandids.customer_id, customer_brandids.brand_id, brands.name, GROUP_CONCAT(brands.name,',')
FROM customer_brandids
INNER JOIN brands
ON customer_brandids.brand_id = brands.brand_id
GROUP by customer_id
```

Comment: Try string_agg. Group_concat is mySQL no?

Comment: Where in the [Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions.html) did you find `group_concat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE customer_brandids AS 
SELECT receipts.receipt_id, receipts.customer_id, receipt_item_details1.brand_id
FROM receipts
LEFT JOIN receipt_item_details1
ON receipts.receipt_id = receipt_item_details1.receipt_id;

SELECT customer_brandids.customer_id, customer_brandids.brand_id, brands.name, string_agg(brands.name,',')
FROM customer_brandids
INNER JOIN brands
ON customer_brandids.brand_id = brands.brand_id
GROUP by customer_id
```

Comment: Thanks when I ran it and replaced "GROUP BY customer_id with "GROUP BY customer_brandids.customer_id" I got this error mesage: "column "customer_brandids.brand_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT customer_brandids.customer_id, customer_brandids.bran...


How do I just aggregate by customer_id?

Comment: @lschra01, you can't unless you make it to an aggregate. I was ignorant to see you had non-aggregate fields there and not included in group by. if you don't care which brand_id you get per customer_id or it is unique per customer_id (same for brands.name) then you could do something like:  max(customer_brandids.brand_id) as brand_id.  - or simply add them to group by.

Answer (score 1):

This aggregates only the brand names:

```
SELECT cb.customer_id, ARRAY_AGG(b.name) as brand_names
FROM customer_brandids cb
INNER JOIN brands b
ON cb.brand_id = b.brand_id
GROUP by cb.customer_id
```

If you want a list of brand IDs as well:

```
SELECT 
    cb.customer_id, 
    ARRAY_AGG(b.brand_id) as brand_ids,
    ARRAY_AGG(b.name) as brand_names
FROM customer_brandids cb
INNER JOIN brands b
ON cb.brand_id = b.brand_id
GROUP by cb.customer_id
```

If you need the list as string list use `string_agg` instead of `array_agg`

```
SELECT 
    cb.customer_id, 
    string_agg(b.brand_id, ',') as brand_ids, -- delete this line if you only need the names
    string_agg(b.name, ',') as brand_names
FROM customer_brandids cb
INNER JOIN brands b
ON cb.brand_id = b.brand_id
GROUP by cb.customer_id
```

Comment: Thanks! just need to list the brands each customer _id buys with comma's seperating each brand.

Comment: I added a string_agg query. Better?

Comment: I didn’t? I thought I did